# jQuery Javascript array 'contains' functionality?

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, arrays

I'm trying to use the jQuery `$.inArray` function to iterate through an array and if there's an element whose text `contains` a particular keyword, remove that element. `$.inArray` is only returning the array index though if the element's text is `equal` to the keyword.

For example given the following array named 'tokens':

```
-   tokens  {...}   Object
    [0] "Starbucks^25^http://somelink"  String
    [1] "McDonalds^34^" String
    [2] "BurgerKing^31^https://www.somewhere.com"   String
```

And a call to `removeElement(tokens, 'McDonalds');` would return the following array:

```
 -  tokens  {...}   Object
    [0] "Starbucks^25^http://somelink"  String
    [1] "BurgerKing^31^https://www.somewhere.com"   String
```

I'm guessing this may be possible using the jQuery `$.grep` or `$.each` function, or maybe `regex`. However, I'm not familiar enough with jQuery to accomplish this.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`grep`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.grep/) is indeed the way to go.

```
function removeElement(array, keyword) {
    return $.grep(array, function (item, i) {
      return item.indexOf(keyword) > -1;
  }, true);
}
```

This looks for the keyword as a substring. If the elements of the array have a particular format (which they appear to, but it isn't stated for certain), alter the test to match the format.

```
function removeElement(array, keyword) {
    var keyRE=new RegExp('^'+keyword+'^');
    return $.grep(array, function (item, i) {
      return keyRE.test(item);
  }, true);
}
```

Note the first '^' is a meta-character matching the beginning of the string; the second simply matches a '^' character.

Comment: I think he wants the result array to contain only things that **don't** have the keyword.

Comment: Pointy has it right. Although if the first removeElement function you've created returned the array index instead of the element, that would work too?

Comment: @YourMomzThaBomb: in the first version (actually, both), the array index is ignored. `a.indexOf(b)` returns the starting index of string `b` in string `a`, or -1 if `b` isn't a substring of `a`.

Answer (score 0):

**edit** oops I totally misunderstood the question.

Well `$.grep` takes an "invert" flag, so you can use it directly:

```
var pattern = /\bword\b/;
var newArray = $.grep(oldArray, function(e) { return pattern.test(e); }, true);
```

Of course, now that I think about it, I could save 5 characters:

```
var newArray = $.grep(oldArray, function(e) { return !pattern.test(e); });
```

Answer (score 0):

This should be clear on its own. Removes all elements from the `tokens` parameter which contain the string passed in in the `search` parameter. Using [filter()](http://api.jquery.com/filter/)

```
function removeElement(tokens, search) {
    var regex = new RegExp(search);
    return $(tokens).filter(function() {
        return !regex.test(this);
    }).toArray();
}
```

If you want you can also specify flags for the regex

e.g.

```
var regex = new RegExp(search, "i");
```

Would remove all elements which contain the search string with case ignored

---

`$.grep` version of the code

```
function removeElement(tokens, search) {
    var regex = new RegExp(search);
    return $.grep(tokens, function(elem, ind) {
        return regex.test(elem);
    }, true);
}
```

Comment: Building a new RegExp instance for each iteration seems kind-of wasteful.